# How to make a new list with 2 positions of a list changed?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a complete newbie in LISP (Common lisp to be exact) and I need to make a function where i can pass the list and 2 arguments, pos1 pos2, that are the elements position in a list, the function should then return a new list with those elements in swapped positions.

Example
(changepos '(a b c d) 0 3) -> (D B C A)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Renzo tried with rotatef, but if I understood it correctly rotatef changes the list I had, my objective is to not change and not destroy the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right- [`rotatef`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm) modifies the given list. But you can use [`copy-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm) or [`copy-tree`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_tre.htm) (for nested lists) inside your function and modify that copy:

```
(defun changepos (list i j)
  (let ((new-list (copy-tree list)))
    (rotatef (nth i new-list)
             (nth j new-list))
    new-list))
```

Tests:

```
> (defparameter *aa* (list 1 2 3 4 5))
*AA*

> (changepos *aa* 1 3)
(1 4 3 2 5)

> *aa*
(1 2 3 4 5)
```